# Adding external JAR´S to JDK

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I just started developing online applications using Servlets and JSP. As you may know we need a doPost method which receives HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) parameters.

My question is the following. I understand I need to import the javax.servlet and javax.servlet.http.* package in order for this to work. I remember once a this crazy teacher who told me I could modify my jdk/jre/lib folder and add those external jar which I would use a lot in order to forget about changing the class path every time I compile a project. Those anyone know how to do this? I already copy the servlet-api.jar into the lib folder but nothing happens..

Thanks

Comment: Put that into ext folder. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext

Comment: You're right, he was crazy. You should use the ones that come with Tomcat or whatever your container is, and with your IDE. If you're not using an IDE, start. You shouldn't mess around with the JRE. Otherwise your code will only work on your computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For external JARs put them in the ext folder.
For example. If you are using 64bit JDK.

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext**

If you are using 32bit version of JDK the path may look like this.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext**

Comment: Note that this answer does not hold for java 10+, as the extension mechanism has been removed, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B

Comment: the new way is the use the classpath argument `-cp` or `classpath`. Assuming you are using the command line that would be `javac -classpath "<path to external JAR file>\<filename>.jar" <application>.java`