# missing library after update to java 1.9

Tags: gradle, build, java-8, guava, java-9

I want to understand why after updating from Java8 to Java9, I need to specify in build.gradle (Gradle Version: 4.5.1 ):

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '24.0-jre'
```

**[EDIT]**: Yes it might sound odd but running gradle with Java 1.8 I builded. Running it with Java 1.9 I needed to add the dependency in the build.gradle file.

Java8: jdk1.8.0_162 builded.

Java9:  jdk-9.0.4 did not.

```
package com.google.common.cache does not exist
```

Is there an obviously answer that I did not notice?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. The first sentence seems to say that you had to add Guava as a dependency to your `build.gradle` _after updating to Java 9_. Does that mean you didn't have it in there before updating? (The best way to reply to this comment is to clarify the question.)

Comment: You should write a `module-info.java` and import this package there

Comment: @VinayPrajapati It does not clarify why running it before it worked..! thx

Comment: Hey @kmxillo please go through JPMS for a while. Also, share more details of your system, classpath and put full error logs here.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I have to build it with 9 but I will run it with 8. For that reason I cant use JPMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not have nothing to do with java 9.

There is a dependency which has changed and does not include `guava` anymore.

Thats why `guava` must be explicity declared.

Answer (score 0):

If what you state in your question is correct, I would assume someone (you?) or some installer added guava in the ext/lib folder of the JDK8 so java would use it from there.

It's actually [the "standard" way of adding external libraries into your JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814400/adding-external-jar%C2%B4s-to-jdk), though I wouldn't do it unless there are strong, case-specific reasons.

Comment: I am very sure I didnt add it.  Thanks.

Comment: have you verified if it is there or not?

Comment: yes. 

/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/lib/ext # ls
cldrdata.jar  dnsns.jar  icedtea-sound.jar  jaccess.jar  localedata.jar  meta-index  nashorn.jar  sunec.jar  sunjce_provider.jar  sunpkcs11.jar  zipfs.jar

Comment: In the question you mentioned "jdk1.8.0_162", so we were talking about JDK, not JRE, right?

Comment: Well I build it with jdk but I run it with jre.
I dont see any ext/lib folder in jdk1.9

Comment: there is always JRE within the JDK. Since you didn't experience build issues with JDK8, you should check the lib/ext of the JRE within JDK8.

Comment: I have checked in jdk8 -> jre/lib/ext and it google.guave does not appear... :( https://gist.github.com/anonymous/011ef85743c123b6637d3dccc9b90d51

Comment: maybe you could just run a full search for guava jar for the machine hosting your jdk8. It's bound to be found somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

The `TypeError: fetch failed` error is usually associated with network problems or issues with executing an HTTP request in JavaScript. This can be caused by various factors, including server access problems, application configuration issues, or network issues.

Here are several steps to help you investigate and fix this error:

1. **Network connection check**: Network problems may cause an error when trying to execute a fetch request. Ensure that your server has a stable network connection.
2. **API endpoint check**: Make sure that the URL you are trying to send a request to is available and functioning correctly. You can use tools like `curl` or `wget` to test the URL's availability from the command line.
3. **Server logs check**: Server logs can provide additional information about the cause of the error. If you're using Docker, you can fetch container logs using the `docker logs <container_id_or_name>` command.
4. **Server or application configuration check**: It's possible that changes were made to the server or application configuration that caused this error. Pay attention to any recent changes in server or application settings.
5. **Firewall and security settings check**: Perhaps a firewall or other security settings are blocking inbound or outbound connections necessary for the fetch request to execute. Check the firewall settings and other security settings on your server.
6. **Code check**: If everything listed above doesn't help, take a look at the code causing the error. Verify if the fetch request is being formed correctly and if the response is being handled appropriately. You might need to use debugging or logging to get more information about what happens during the request execution.

Remember, other steps may be needed to solve the error for your specific situation. If you continue to encounter issues, consider reaching out to the developer community or your hosting provider's support service for help.